# NameError: name 'word' is not defined even though i clearly defined it earlier in my code

Tags: python

```
if difficulty_choice == "easy":
    word = str(choice(easy))
    word_length="The word you\'ve been given contains %s letters"
    length=len(word)
    print word_length % length

###########

list(word)
```

I defined word in a function, and then called up on the function. Everything works fine up till that point. However, afterward i tried to use the list function on word. Thats where i recieve the error, which tells me 'word' is not defined.

Is there something wrong with defining a variable in a function?

Comment: What happens when difficulty_choice isn't "easy"...?

Comment: please post the full code, so we can see where an how it is defined.

Answer (score 5):

No, `word` is only bound (assigned to) if `difficulty_choice == "easy"` is True.

If you have any other value in `difficulty_choice`, then the block of code under the `if` statement is not executed and `word` does not exist:

```
>>> if False:
...     word = 'Hello!'
... 
>>> word
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

You can always assign an empty value to `word` *before* the `if` statement:

```
word = ''
if difficulty_choice == "easy":
```